# JQuery returns NaN value while calculating multiple inputs in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple input rows and all rows have a total column at the end. Now, I want to put the total result of each rows in  column Total. I tried but it returns **NaN** value instead of total result. Attached is my view & script please help  what I am missing???  Thanks

```js
$('body').on('change', '.bgpending, .registered', function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var totalRow = 0;
  el.closest('.dosiaPlace').find('input').each(function() {
    totalRow = totalRow + parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  el.closest('.dosiaPlace').find('.total-row').val(totalRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dosiaPlace">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>@lang('dashboard.pastyear'):</label>
    <input type="number" value="0" class="form-control bgpending" name="bgpending[]" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>@lang('dashboard.warida'):</label>
    <input type="number" value="0" class="form-control registered" name="registered[]" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>@lang('dashboard.total'):</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control total-row" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: JS code result]

Comment: can you check logs of this value $(this).val() and make sure you are getting it right? so that hou can see what parseInt is getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container, the `.dosiaPlace`, I presume, has 3 inputs: the `.bgpending`, the `.registered`, and the `.total-row`. Your `el.closest('.dosiaPlace').find('input')` finds all 3 of those, *including the `.total-row`*. But the `.total-row` is empty (initially), so

```
totalRow = totalRow + parseInt($(this).val());
```

for it results in

```
totalRow = totalRow + parseInt('');
```

And the empty string can't be `parseInt`'d (results in `NaN`). (You also probably don't want to be including the `.total-row` anyway)

Use `input:not(.total-row')` instead of `input`:

```js
$('body').on('change', '.bgpending, .registered', function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var totalRow = 0;
  el.closest('body').find('input:not(.total-row)').each(function() {
    totalRow = totalRow + parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  el.closest('body').find('.total-row').val(totalRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>@lang('dashboard.pastyear'):</label>
  <input type="number" value="0" class="form-control bgpending" name="bgpending[]" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>@lang('dashboard.warida'):</label>
  <input type="number" value="0" class="form-control registered" name="registered[]" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>@lang('dashboard.total'):</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control total-row" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable get null value or NaN just asign o if it is nan or empty

```
if(totalRow=='' || totalRow ==NaN )
{
  totalRow=0;  
}
```